# TortoiseHG: Close a named branch

Tags: version-control, tortoisehg

I can't seem to figure out how to close a currently open branch when committing. Here is what I am doing:

1. Open the commit window
2. Type a message   Click the "branch:
   branchName" button
3. In the box that pops up, click
   "Close current named branch"
4. Hit OK
5. Hit Commit.

And yet, the branch remains open. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What TortoiseHg version are you using?

Answer (score 3):

It would help to see if you can reproduce this issue [with 1.1.x or at least 1.0.4 version](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/ReleaseNotes) of TortoiseHg, because:

- [issue 879](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/issue/879/branch-closing-doesnt-work) is very close from what you experienced
- I don't see issue 879 in the [1.0.1 release note](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/src/bcf0eaf6db6a/ReleaseNotes.txt)